# How to make alcohol in the ocean?

Tags: culture, ocean, merfolk

Last night my friends and I visited a pub in Atlantis and have a great time with the merfolk, everything seems pretty normal until I noticed there they don't serves vodka, in fact they don't consume alcoholic drinks at all. So we decided to do a cultural exchange right there right now, we took some clamshells and cone shells and tied around our naked bodies using seaweeds and seahorses. However the merfolk are interested in alcohol since we already bragged for 2 high tides and 2 low tides, I don't want to ruin the mood so can I brew/produce alcohol in-situ in the ocean without going ashore? The merfolk are willing to help me with foraging the seabed too.

Answer (score 1):

**In theory it should be possible... But a quick aside - the mental image of a Mermaid projectile vomitting because they can't handle their liquor is hilarious**

Yeast can survive in Salt Water - but according to various Baking websites, Salt water acts as an inhibitor. Getting the Yeast in the first place might be a bit tricky - but let's assume you've taken a container down to the Ocean floor.

You can ferment Seaweed and Kelp (although sources indicate it tastes like Sour Wine) - No fires, but a Geothermal vent would provide a nice Heat Source to get the reaction going and to overcome the issues with the Salt Water.

However, if we have a sealed container and a means of using purified water, it would make our lives a *lot* easier.

The final problem is that our Seaweed wine would taste awful and be at best about 15% (which is enough to get drunk on if you are determined) - but let's make things difficult for ourselves - we want to distill our Seaweed wine to make Seaweed Liquor (if it's going to taste like Arse, I want to drink the absolute minimum necessary) - and for this, we go back to our Thermal vent - with a series of sealed containers, using the ambient water to cool the system (and condense/concentrate the alcohol) - we could get a nice 40% or higher Seaweed Liquor.

I wouldn't want to taste it personally - but All-in-all with a sealed container, some live Yeast, preferably purified water and a Geothermal vent - We's making us some Ocean floor Moonshine - Woo!

Comment: Trust me, a few pints of 15% is more than enough to get the average person bladdered. We really should have bottled that stuff instead of leaving the barrel on the side at that party.

Comment: @Separatrix - Oh, don't I know it - but if it tastes bad, I'd take a few shots of it over a couple of glasses of it.

Comment: We can make it tasty! Don't settle for gross seaweed liquor. Repeated fractional distillation lets you select which chemicals to discard and which to keep until it doesn't matter whether you started with grapes or garbage, what's left is vodka. If at first it tastes like swill, distill, distill, distill, distill!